# Format Date while fetching the result of query

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

Ok, here is another one: I want to get the output from a mysql-query in a specific date format. Unfortunatley my code does not work. It must have something to do with "->format()", since without it I get the expected result. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        something,
        date
    FROM 
        table
    ";

$querynav = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querynav)){

    $answer[] = array(
        'something' => $row['something'],
        'date' => (new DateTime($row['date']))->format('d.m.Y')
        );

}
```

Comment: Provide the **exact** `$row['date']` value, the actual result and the expected result. PS: just a side note of all 18 lines of code you've provided 17 are irrelevant to the question

Comment: @princecharming (zerkms): $row['date'] value is something like "2013-05-14 22:42:00", actual result is an "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR"-error, expected result is in my 18 lines of code ;)

Comment: you cannot create an object and invoke its method in a single line. So split the expression into 2 lines: 1. create `DateTime` object 2. call its `format()` method

Comment: @zerkms: you are right, with two lines it is working. Still wondering why, but thank you!

Comment: "Still wondering why" --- that's the php's syntax rules

Comment: Still wondering why...

Comment: another question for you to wonder - why variables start with `$`

Comment: ... and why you are such a niceguy...

Comment: doesnt matter - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mysql [**DATE_FORMAT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT something, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%Y') as date FROM table;
```

If you want to do in PHP, you can do like this.

```
$answer[] = array(
        'something' => $row['something'],
        'date'      => date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date']))
);
```

You don't have to use `strtotime()` function if your value is **timestamp**.

Comment: +1 U missed "**as date**": `SELECT something, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%Y') as date FROM table;`

Comment: No possibility to let php do the job?

Comment: @user2370579 I edited my answer with PHP code. Please see that

Comment: @Edwin Alex: Thank you so much! I will use your method. It is much simpler than my try and only one line of code. Great!

Answer (score 2):

If your `$row['date']` have date, do this:

```
$newdate =  date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

And you can the date in `12.03.2013` format.

**EDIT:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querynav)){
    $newdate =  date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row['date']));

    $answer[] = array(
        'something' => $row['something'],
        'date' => $newdate 
        );

}
```

Comment: I want to to something like this within the fetch_assoc environment. Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit section please.. (But, It may need little modification)

Answer (score -1):

```
'date' => ((new DateTime($row['date']))->format('d.m.Y'))
```

EDIT 1:

```
'date' => (new DateTime($row['date']))->format('d-m-Y')
```